# "docker builder rm" fails

Tags: docker, buildx

The command `docker builder rm jaeger-build` takes 135 seconds and fails with "error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon ...."

Is there another way to force the removal of a Docker builder?  (I have a working Docker daemon, `docker ps` works, it is only the `buildx` commands that have this problem.)

The command `docker builder ls` takes 75 seconds to run and produces this output:

```
NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT  STATUS  PLATFORMS
desktop-linux   docker                   
  desktop-linux desktop-linux    running linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
jaeger-build    docker-container         
  jaeger-build  jaeger-build     Get "https://192.168.99.101:2376/v1.24/containers/buildx_buildkit_jaeger-build/json": context deadline exceeded
default *       docker                   
  default       default          running linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

I am using Docker Desktop for Mac, version 20.10.11.  `docker buildx version` reports "v0.6.3" and I don't know if that is recent or old.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this.

"Docker Desktop => Troubleshoot => Clean/Purge Data" did not work, and Docker didn't restart after "Docker Desktop => Troubleshoot => Reset to factory defaults" or after Uninstall.

The steps that seemed to work:

- Remove my settings using `mv ~/.docker ~/.corrupt-docker`
- Reboot the Mac

I did those things after the steps that didn't work.